# Can I order an item from another country whilst in Turkey?

Tags: borders, turkey, mail

I was thinking of ordering down pants through Amazon whilst in Turkey. There is a message giving more detail on the issue of this product being sent from abroad. The machine translation says:

"For shipments coming from abroad, customs and import costs are paid on your behalf. You do not need to make any additional payment. Please check this link for Turkey Import Customs Restrictions and make sure you meet the conditions before ordering. Amazon Turkey is not the importer, distributor, seller or publisher of the product sent from abroad in your cart. *Therefore, as an importer and end user, your Turkish ID number is needed to carry out your customs procedures.* You can find detailed information in the Privacy Statement .

Since I am only a tourist and have no Turkish ID number, is it impossible to order products from abroad through Amazon?

https://www.amazon.com.tr/Naturehike-Pantolon-Ge%C3%A7irmez-Kamp%C3%A7%C4%B1l%C4%B1k-Da%C4%9Fc%C4%B1l%C4%B1k/dp/B0B8CR926R?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&psc=1&smid=A106RGEIVIG2HU&th=1
[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing the check-out process to see if it allows you to go through without a Turkish ID? Alternatively, you can try ordering on Amazon DE (for instance) and have it delivered in Turkey and see if that works.

Comment: Have it sent to a friend in your home country and then have them ship it to you in Turkey... much easier... usually. But, disclaimer: there's never any guarantee that any country's customs won't seize your package for whatever obscure reason. You might want to look up the duty-free import value for your item (if you can) and make it is under that (or at least that your friend declares that it is under that upon shipping)